# STM32cubeide generated code first address erased when perform reset in stm32l152re nucleo

Tags: stm32cubeide

I have migrated my `keil` code generated from HAL cube to `stm32cubeide` because of size constraint. The code is working fine when used in debugging. But when run code stand alone using st link utility, **it is working fine for the first time but when perform reset its first address erased and controller gone to undefined state.** Can anyone have any idea regarding this problem and how can I fix it.

[image]